# (Android NDK) Strings containing non-ASCII characters get cut off

Tags: c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to port a program written in C to Android using the NDK and JNI, and I'm stuck with a ridiculous problem which is driving me crazy.

To make it short, if I do this...

```
char str[1024];
sprintf(str, "Hellö, this is söme stränge letters.");
```

...*strlen(str)* returns 35, as expected. Right?

But if I include a specifier, and do this...

```
char str[1024];
sprintf(str, "Hellö again. Here's a number: %d", 1);
```

...*strlen(str)* returns 4.

Do you see what's happening? It appears the NDK can't (or won't?) accept non-ASCII characters in strings, if I try to format them.

Any time I include an ASCII character >127 in the format string, it just gets cut off. Like it was NULL-terminated.

Is this a bug? Is this expected behaviour?

Ultimately, my question is: **What can I do to solve this?**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked to see the encoding of str?  It's most likely encoded in a non-ASCII friendly way, such as UTF-8.

Comment: @bruceg No, sorry, I haven't. How do I do that?

Comment: _"How do I do that?"_ Do a hexdump of the contents of `str` (i.e. for a byte with the value 0, print "00"; for the value 255, print "FF", etc).

Comment: @Michael Thank you, but before I can go ahead and encode the string, I must first assemble it. As it is now, I can't even _create_ the string to be encoded since sprintf() refuses these characters..?

Answer (score 2):

A "preview" version of Android 5.0 had some issues that were fixed in the final release.  See [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78669) for more information.

If you get a hex dump of the .o file (with e.g. `xxd` on Linux) and search for a fragment of the string, you can see how it's encoded in the executable. If it's valid UTF-8 -- I get `c3 b6` for 'ö' when I compile with desktop gcc -- then it should work.  If it's using some other encoding, the Android libc may reject it as invalid.

If the string in the binary doesn't appear to be UTF-8, check your makefiles for things like `-fexec-charset=`.

Comment: I looked at it with HxD and if I'm reading it right, "ö" is just one byte and it's F6 in hex. I also don't have any `-fexec-charset=` in my makefiles. I am building with ndk-build on Windows. My build target is android-22 (5.1.1) and my phone is 5.1.1. I can't get sprintf() to accept these characters...

Comment: That explains the rejection. You need to get a UTF-8 encoded representation of the character into the string. (As an experiment, try adding it explicitly, e.g. `"Hell\xc3\xb6 again"`.) Get a hex dump of your source file to see if your editor is writing UTF-8 or CP-1252 -- gcc may not understand what you're intending. If you can't configure your editor to write UTF-8, you may need to specify `-finput-charset=` to gcc to match whatever it's actually using. FWIW, note in the bug report I linked some examples of people who found it easier to drop in a replacement `sprintf()`.